# Active Record Query, return Users with over a certain number of check_ins at a restaurant

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my db I have `Users` that have `check_ins`. A `check_in` is tied to one restaurant with `restaurant_id`. What's the most efficient way to get all Users who have checked in at a given restaurant more then X times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write effect Active Record queries, you must first know how to write effective SQL queries. As with any programming problem, the first step is to break it down into smaller tasks.

### TL;DR

Don't do two queries when you just need one.

```ruby
users_with_check_in_counts = User.select('users.*, COUNT(*) AS check_in_count')
                               .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN check_ins ON users.id = check_ins.user_id')
                               .where(check_ins: { restaurant_id: 1 })
                               .group(:id)
                               .having('check_in_count > ?', 3)
                               .all
# => [ #<User id=2, name="Nick", ..., check_in_count=4>,
#      #<User id=4, name="Jordan", ..., check_in_count=4> ]

nick = users_with_check_in_counts.first
puts nick.check_in_count
# => 4
```

---

### Prelude

Your `check_ins` table probably looks something like this:

```
  id | restaurant_id | user_id | ...
-----+---------------+---------+-----
   1 |             1 |       1 | ... 
   2 |             1 |       2 |
   3 |             1 |       2 |
   4 |             1 |       2 |
   5 |             1 |       2 |
   6 |             1 |       3 |
   7 |             1 |       3 |
   8 |             1 |       3 |
   9 |             1 |       4 |
  10 |             1 |       4 |
  11 |             1 |       4 |
  12 |             1 |       4 |
  13 |             2 |       1 |
 ... |           ... |     ... | ...
```

In the above table we have 12 check-ins at the restaurant with `restaurant_id = 1`. The user with `user_id = 1` checked in once, `2` checked in four times, `3` checked in twice, and `4` checked in four times.

### The naïve way

The naive way to do this would be to break it down into the following tasks:

1. Get the `check_ins` records for the restaurant:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM check_ins WHERE restaurant_id = 1;
   ```
2. Get the number of check-ins for each user for the restaurants by grouping by `user_id` and counting the number of records in each group:

   ```sql
     SELECT check_ins.*, COUNT(user_id) AS check_in_count
       FROM check_ins
      WHERE restaurant_id = 1
   GROUP BY user_id
   ```
3. Restrict the results to groups with at least than *N* records, e.g. `N = 3`:

   ```sql
     SELECT check_ins.*, COUNT(user_id) AS check_in_count
       FROM check_ins
      WHERE restaurant_id = 1
   GROUP BY user_id
     HAVING check_in_count >= 3
   ```
4. Translate that into an Active Record query:

   ```ruby
   check_in_counts = CheckIn.where(restaurant_id: 1).group(:user_id)
                       .having("user_count > ?", 3).count
   # => { 2 => 4, 4 => 4 }
   ```
5. Write a second query to get the associated users:

   ```ruby
   User.find(check_in_counts.keys)
   # => [ #<User id=2, ...>, #<User id=4, ...> ]
   ```

That works, but there's something smelly about it—oh, it's that we're using a *relational database*. If we have a query that gets records from `check_ins`, we should just get the related `users` in the same query.

### A better way

Now, it's relatively obvious that we could take our SQL query from (3) above and add a `JOIN users ON check_ins.user_id = users.id` to get the associated users records, but that leaves us in a bind because we still want Active Record to give us User objects, not CheckIn objects. To do that we need a different query, one that starts with `users` and joins `check_ins`.

To get there, we use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
         SELECT *
           FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN check_ins ON users.id = check_ins.user_id
          WHERE restaurant_id = 1;
```

The above query will give us results like this:

```
 id | name   | ... | restaurant_id | user_id
----+--------+-----+---------------+---------
  1 | Sarah  |   1 |             1 |       1
  2 | Nick   |   1 |             1 |       2
  2 | Nick   |   1 |             1 |       2
  2 | Nick   |   1 |             1 |       2
  2 | Nick   |   1 |             1 |       2
  3 | Carmen |   1 |             1 |       3
  3 | Carmen |   1 |             1 |       3
  3 | Carmen |   1 |             1 |       3
  4 | Jordan |   1 |             1 |       4
  4 | Jordan |   1 |             1 |       4
  4 | Jordan |   1 |             1 |       4
  4 | Jordan |   1 |             1 |       4
```

This looks familiar: it has all of the data from `check_ins`, with the data from `users` added on to each row. That's what `LEFT OUTER JOIN` does. Now, just like before, we can use `GROUP BY` to group by user IDs and `COUNT` to count the records in each group, with `HAVING` to restrict the results to users with a certain number of check-ins:

```sql
         SELECT users.*, COUNT(*) AS check_in_count
           FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN check_ins ON users.id = check_ins.user_id
          WHERE restaurant_id = 1
       GROUP BY users.id
         HAVING check_in_count >= 3;
```

This gives us:

```
 id | name   | ... | check_in_count
----+--------+-----+----------------
  2 | Nick   | ... |             4
  4 | Jordan |     |             4
```

Perfect!

### Finally...

Now all we have to do is translate this into an Active Record query. It's pretty straightforward:

```ruby
users_with_check_in_counts = User.select('users.*, COUNT(*) AS check_in_count')
                               .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN check_ins ON users.id = check_ins.user_id')
                               .where(check_ins: { restaurant_id: 1 })
                               .group(:id)
                               .having('check_in_count > ?', 3)
                               .all
# => [ #<User id=2, name="Nick", ..., check_in_count=4>,
#      #<User id=4, name="Jordan", ..., check_in_count=4> ]

nick = users_with_check_in_counts.first
puts nick.check_in_count
# => 4
```

And best of all, it performs just one query.

### Bonus: Scope it

That's a pretty long Active Record query. If there's only one place in your app where you're going to have a query like this, it might be okay to use it that way. If I were you, though, I would turn it into a scope:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_check_in_count, ->(opts) {
    opts[:at_least] ||= 1

    select('users.*, COUNT(*) AS check_in_count')
      .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN check_ins ON users.id = check_ins.user_id')
      .where(check_ins: { restaurant_id: opts[:restaurant_id] })
      .group(:id)
      .having('check_in_count >= ?', opts[:at_least])
  }

  # ...
end
```

Then:

```ruby
User.with_check_in_count(at_least: 3, restaurant_id: 1)
# ...or just...
User.with_check_in_count(restaurant_id: 1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the very complete response. One correction is the `.where(restaurant_id: 1)` needs to be `.where(check_ins: {restaurant_id: id})`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check this with your exact model schema, but something like this should work:

```
check_in_counts = CheckIn.group(:user_id).having(restaurant_id: 3).having('COUNT(id) > 10').count
```

This will return a `Hash` with `user_id` => `check_in_count` values, which you can use to fetch all the `User` objects:

```
users = User.find(check_in_counts.keys)
```